# Bitwise issue in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am trying to use bitwise operators on uint64_t type.  When I run this, I get output of 37 (47 - 10) bits even though it needs to be 54 bits (64-10 bits) long.  How can I fix this?

```
uint64_t temp = addr; //(addr input - 11111111110100011010111011011111000101111001000)
temp = temp >> 10;
return temp; //returns 37 bits only as input is 47 bits.
```

Output:
temp is now 1111111111010001101011101101111100010

Comment: Show more code. What is `addr`?

Comment: addr is also uint64_t with the value in binary given in comments.

Comment: There are 64 bits in an uint64_t. You're not seeing the leading zeroes.

Comment: "even though it needs to be 54 bits (64-10 bits) long" - no, it will be 64 bits long because you use a `uint64_t`. Apart from that, what do you expect, when your initial number had only 47 significant bits?

Comment: What do you mean by _"it needs to be 54 bits"_? What do you expect the topmost bits to contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp` is 64 bits because that's how you declared it.

When you print it, the initial zeroes don't show unless you specify that you want them to show in your print statement.

Try with `addr = 1000000000100000000010000000001000000000100000000010000000001000` (or any other 64 bit number starting with a `1`) and you will see.